# How to uninstall matplotlib from OS X 10.10.3

Tags: macos, python-2.7, matplotlib

After installing matplotlib via pip I am now unable to import matplotlib from the OS X Python and I would like to uninstall it and start again. I think I have multiple copies of matplotlib  and this may be causing the problem. See below.

---

```
*cbhe:pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tornado in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing>=1.5.6 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nose in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): backports.ssl-match-hostname in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): certifi in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)*
```

---

Can someone tell me how to uninstall matplotlib. I am not a unix software person and would really like to have the specific unix command(s) needed to make the uninstall.